# build tensorflow from source error: Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

I need to build tensorflow from source.

After `git clone` and run the following check command:

```
bazel test -c opt -- //tensorflow/... -//tensorflow/compiler/... -//tensorflow/contrib/lite/...
```

And I get the following error:

```
bazel test -c opt -- //tensorflow/... -//tensorflow/compiler/... -//tensorflow/contrib/lite/...
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/home/rich/research/installations/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc

INFO: Invocation ID: 1a1c9f70-531e-49a0-b8e7-9f4d7ab4b24b
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': The native http_archive rule is deprecated. load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive") for a drop-in replacement.
Use --incompatible_remove_native_http_archive=false to temporarily continue using the native rule.

ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': The native http_archive rule is deprecated. load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive") for a drop-in replacement.
Use --incompatible_remove_native_http_archive=false to temporarily continue using the native rule.

INFO: Elapsed time: 0.046s

INFO: 0 processes.

FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a bazel version that is too new.

The latest released bazel version according to https://blog.bazel.build/ is 0.22, but the latest bazel version mentioned in the "Tested build configurations" section of https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source is 0.15.0 (used for tensorflow 1.12)

Comment: yes, I use an older version bazel, it works. Thank you .